# FileInputstream android garbage

Tags: android, fileinputstream, libusb

I am using this code to read input stream  but its not working It s giving garbage value in buffer. what's wrong with the code below:
//mInputStream is an object of FileInputStream

```
buf = new byte[4];
int ret = 0;

l("run");
try {
    while ( (ret = mInputStream.read(buf) )!= -1) {
        l("No.of bytes received:"+ret);
        l("Data received length :"+buf.length);
        l("Data received: "+buf.toString());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    l("IO exception in receiving");
}
```

Comment: Could you post the output of the code and the initialization of the mInputStream variable?

Comment: I am using USBmanager class .using above code I can get the number of bytes received correctly but the code buf.toString() returns garbage.FileInputstream is initialised as follows:                              FileDescriptor fd =  UsbManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).openAccessory(accessory).getFileDescriptor();                            mInputStream=new FileInputStream(fd);

Comment: Can you post the exact output please?

Comment: output is::                                                     D/USB     ( 4751): No.of bytes received:10
D/USB     ( 4751): Data received length :10
D/USB     ( 4751): Data received: [B@40533870        input for this data is "123" (String) .I am using libusb library to sent data. command is:                                                               response = libusb_bulk_transfer(handle,OUT,buffer,10, &transferred,0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could try this code:

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mInputStream));
StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    total.append(line);
}
l("String: " + total);
```

and post the output?

Comment: I am not getting data with above code.but if I change buf.toString() to new String(buf) in earlier code i can get data but it shown like:7@�������������� for input 7.

Answer (score 0):

As you know every class in java extends Object class.  Every instance of any class has a toString method inherited from the Object class, which prints out [name of class]@[instance id].  It seems like buf.toString() returns a class name (B) and its ID (40533870).  Try checking the contents of buf one index at a time.